# detect keypression when minimized and trayicon

Tags: c#, keypress, minimize

For my test I've created a little program in C# to detect key presses with this code:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F12)  MessageBox.Show("f12 pressed");
}
```

This works fine when the form is focused and active. I've spent many time to find how to set it for works when minimized, I found a solution here to add system tray icon. I followed solution but didn't work anymore.

When i minimize it, the icon tray appears and works, but i didn't detect key presses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form will only receive keypress events when it has focus, to receive other keypress events you would need to register a global hotkey.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

Comment: Create a new class for the HotKey code, then add the "usage" code from the article in to your current form code