# how to call a specific function by pressing ctrl+1?

Tags: c#, winforms, key

I've a **C#** application which performs a specific action whenever i press **CTRL+1** keys.
But the problem is **CTRL+1** method only works when the form is in focus. when I minimize the form to system tray then **CTRL+1** doesn't work. can anyone tell me how to track pressed keys even the form is **minimized**?

Comment: Take a look at [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You have an example [there](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3055/System-Hotkey-Component)

Comment: You have to register to a global hotkey:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734453/detect-keypression-when-minimized-and-trayicon][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734453/detect-keypression-when-minimized-and-trayicon

Comment: I believe that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp) could help you out.

Good Luck!