# Detecting events while minimized C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a C# Windows Forms Program that responds to events of a change in master volume by showing the current volume as it changes using NAudio.

It functions as it should in that...however it stops Listening to events once out of focus.

I tried creating multiple threads as I thought minimizing only pauses the main thread but the problem remained, any ideas?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734453/detect-keypression-when-minimized-and-trayicon

Comment: How are you getting the volume events?

Comment: Yes but that's about keypress events, doesn't intercepting volume change events make a difference ? @cullub

Comment: Using NAudio Library and an MMDeviceEnumerator @PeterRitchie